# Is there a way to keep the OpenStreetMap background image when resizing the internet window browser?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to include in my browser an OpenStreetMap map as a background image. For this I use the Leaflet JavaScript library. To include the OpenStreetMap map, I open the browser console and I call the JavaScript function I built, allowing to include the map. The map appears in the browser as a background image, but afterwards when I close the console browser, the browser window is resized an the map disappears. Is there a way to keep the map when I close the console browser? I tried with ResizeSensor JavaScript constructor but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to put the interactive map as a background image as opposed to a PNG or a JPEG? Those are easier and make the page less bulky by sparing the whole script and dom fuss the map would otherwise add.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I want to include the interactive map is bacause I am working on a browser software developpement that needs interactive map as a background image. The trick I am looking for is to find a JavaScript solution to keep the map when I close the console browser, so when the browser window is resized. Would you know some JavaScript trick allowing me to keep the map as a background image on the browser window? I tried to use the ResizeSensor JavaScript constructor but it doesn't work.

Comment: @A.Titta it is almost impossible to tell what could be your issue without seeing any code, especially given the fact that your case sounds very specific. Please make sure to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ghybs: I tried this piece of code I built up to keep the map when the browser window is resized : function resizeMap(){
 
 var element = document.querySelector(".geBackgroundPage");
 
 var height = element.clientHeight;
 var width = element.clientWidth;
 
 if (height == false && width == false){
  window.onresize = fondCarteTypeOsm();
 }
}             fondCarteTypeOsm() is the function that allows me to put the interactive map as a background image ; and ".geBackgroundPage" is the element wherein the map appears (the background window).

Comment: @ghybs: When I type in the browser console "fondCarteTypeOsm();" the map well appears on the background window. Afterwards I type in the console "resizeMap();" to see whether when closing the console the map stays. But unfortunately it doesn't work, the map still disappears. Hope the piece of code I put above is enought clear. If you are some ideas on how to help me with my problem, it would be well appreciated. Thank you in advance.